# Active admin not showing all input fields just last one

Tags: forms, input, activeadmin

I have this code inside app/admin/products.rb. I have problem with that I can see just one input field at time(the last one listed) or just submit button. Does it could be because of some syntax mistakes ? But there is no any error messages.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do 
   f.input :name,:label => "Name"
   f.input :photo, :as => :file
   f.input :category, :collection => @category
   f.input :manufacturer, :collection => @manufacturer
   f.actions do
   f.action :submit, :button_html => { :class => "primary", :disable_with => 'Wait...' } 
 end 
end
end
```

Product model looks like this

```
 attr_accessible :category_id, :description, :manufacturer_id, :name, :photo 
 extend FriendlyId
has_attached_file :photo,
 :styles => {
   :thumb=> "100x100#",
   :large => "290x170",
    :medium=> "120x120"} 
friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]
belongs_to :manufacturer
belongs_to :category
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form should be inside the block.

Example

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do

form do |f|
  f.inputs "Details" do
    f.input :title
    f.input :published_at, :label => "Publish Post At"
    f.input :category
  end
  f.inputs "Content" do
    f.input :body
  end
  f.actions
end
```

end

Here is more info 
http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html